# Try-with-resource autoclose issues

Tags: java

I am working with a legacy code, where I see certain DB transaction initiated in try-with-Resources close block. I understand the DB resource will be closed once the code in the try block is executed. Can somebody help me, how can I over-ride or bypass the autoclosing, in this case ?   I am working with the legacy code and that too for very short time, so want not to change too much of code, and invite unit tests failures.

Comment: So, you want to introduce bugs in the code by not closing the resources that must be closed? Why?

Comment: Without any code and more specific input on what exactly you intend to do/change ... we cant help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't hack your way round this by assigning the try-with-resources identifier to `null`, or a similar technique: Java does not let you do that.

That's a good thing as it would pollute your source code making reversal of the temporary change difficult.

Fortunately there are better ways: If you're able to change the resources class slightly, you could always build a `disableClose()` method on it, which sets some flag so that the subsequent `close()` call is benign. If you can't change the resources class then derive a class from it and create an instance of that instead. Despite this potentially requiring boilerplate constructor code, it might be a better approach since then you could build something that tracks the instances that have not been closed correctly.

Adopting either technique means that you can weed out this temporary change quite simply by removing the `disableClose()` method or the derived class once you're done with it, which will introduce compilation failures that you can fix one by one.

Possible implementation of the derived class approach:

```
public class Foo extends YourResource
{
    // ToDo - add constructors here.

    private boolean disable = false;

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        // ToDo - consider maintaining a collection of unclosed instances.
        if (!disable){
            super.close();
        }
    }

    public void disableClose()
    {
        disable = true;
    }     
}
```